# T-SQL script to check if index rebuild operations are online are off

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, index, sql-server-2014, maintenance

I wanted to see if it was possible to determine whether my indexes are rebuilt online or offline with some T-SQL. I'm currently trying to troubleshoot extra disk space used during a rebuild procedure and I thought this may me a good place to start.

Comment: You want to know if a rebuild running right now is online, or if a rebuild that happened last Tuesday was online?

Comment: Unless you explicitly specify in your scripts to do it online, **default is offline**. A quick check in your script will answer your question.

Answer (score 2):

Referencing the information in [Capture Index Maintenance Operations](http://www.sqlsolutionsgroup.com/capture-index-maintenance-operations/#codesyntax_2), you *might* be able to use Extended Events to capture online index operations.

From that post:

Create the Extended Event

**Note that this example is using the Ring Buffer, so you may want to pick a different target.  The example is also looking for database_id = 5, so adjust accordingly**

```
-- Create the Event Session
IF EXISTS (
        SELECT *
        FROM sys.server_event_sessions
        WHERE NAME = 'OnlineIXOps'
        )
    DROP EVENT SESSION OnlineIXOps ON SERVER;
GO

CREATE EVENT SESSION OnlineIXOps ON SERVER
    --+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
    --+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
    /* The online index operations */
    --ADD EVENT sqlserver.progress_report_online_index_operation
    --+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
    --+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
    ADD EVENT sqlserver.progress_report_online_index_operation (
    ACTION(sqlserver.database_name, sqlserver.client_hostname, sqlserver.client_app_name, sqlserver.sql_text, sqlserver.session_id)
    --Change this to match the database in question, 
    WHERE sqlserver.database_id = 5
    ) ADD TARGET package0.ring_buffer
    WITH (MAX_DISPATCH_LATENCY = 5 SECONDS)
GO

-- Start the Event Session
ALTER EVENT SESSION OnlineIXOps ON SERVER STATE = START;
GO
```

Now, run some kind of online index operation.  From the post:

```
ALTER INDEX IX_PolicyUserRole ON PolicyUserRole REBUILD PARTITION = ALL WITH (online = ON)
```

Having rebuilt that index online, you can then query the Event session with tsql using a query similar to the following:

```
SELECT event_data.value('(event/@name)[1]', 'varchar(50)') AS event_name
    ,event_data.value('(event/@timestamp)[1]', 'varchar(50)') AS TIMESTAMP
    ,event_data.value('(event/action[@name="database_name"]/value)[1]', 'varchar(max)') AS DBName
    ,event_data.value('(event/data[@name="object_name"]/value)[1]', 'varchar(max)') AS ObjName
    ,event_data.value('(event/data[@name="index_name"]/value)[1]', 'varchar(max)') AS index_name
    ,event_data.value('(event/data[@name="partition_number"]/value)[1]', 'varchar(max)') AS PartitionNumber
    ,event_data.value('(event/action[@name="session_id"]/value)[1]', 'varchar(max)') AS SessionID
    ,event_data.value('(event/data[@name="build_stage"]/value)[1]', 'varchar(max)') AS Build_Stage
    ,event_data.value('(event/data[@name="build_stage"]/text)[1]', 'varchar(max)') AS BuildStage_Description
    ,event_data.value('(event/action[@name="client_hostname"]/value)[1]', 'varchar(max)') AS Client_hostName
    ,event_data.value('(event/action[@name="client_app_name"]/value)[1]', 'varchar(max)') AS Client_AppName
    ,event_data.value('(event/action[@name="sql_text"]/value)[1]', 'varchar(max)') AS sql_text
    ,event_data.value('(event/data[@name="duration"]/value)[1]', 'Decimal(18,2)') / 1000 AS Duration_ms
    ,event_data.value('(event/data[@name="rows_inserted"]/value)[1]', 'varchar(max)') AS rows_inserted
FROM (
    SELECT evnt.query('.') AS event_data
    FROM (
        SELECT CAST(target_data AS XML) AS TargetData
        FROM sys.dm_xe_sessions AS s
        INNER JOIN sys.dm_xe_session_targets AS t ON s.address = t.event_session_address
        WHERE s.NAME = 'OnlineIXOps'
            AND t.target_name = 'ring_buffer'
        ) AS tab
    CROSS APPLY TargetData.nodes('RingBufferTarget/event') AS split(evnt)
    ) AS evts(event_data)
ORDER BY TIMESTAMP
    ,Build_Stage
```

When  I tested a non-online rebuild, there we no Extended Events captured.

Answer (score 0):

What's your rebuild procedure?  Your best bet is just to check the code and see what it's doing, is there a reason why you can't do that?

Comment: Hi David, It occurs within an external 3rd party application and unfortunately we can't contact them today